# Flutter pull to refresh on lower part of screen

Tags: flutter, pull-to-refresh

[image]

I have a app that looks like the picture above. 
When i swipe right or left, page switches along with the pageview content. but NOT the image part, it stays still.

When i implement pull to refresh on this case, the gap opens above image part showing progress indicator and refreshes.

**I want the refresher crack open between image and content part, how do i achieve this?**

thank you so much for reply in advance, you are the hero.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: [
        const Expanded(
          child: SizedBox(height: 200), //The 'Image Part'
        ),
        SmartRefresher(
          child: PageView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, state) => Column(
children:[SizedBox(height:200),PageContent()], itemCount: 3),//The 'Content Part'
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Example code added above, this represents what i would like to implement, I want the refresher only accessible inside PageContent()
but i could not because it contains Column inside

Comment: Please include codes on what you have tried so far

Comment: I think making your stack a column should solve your problem....you want your image to be in top and your bottom part to scroll and refresh...so if your SmaetRefresher is working fine making your stack a column should solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

seems like an issue with your stack.
if you want the image part to also follow the swipe it has to be within the `pageview.builder`.
For the refresh, under `pageview.builder` wrap the content part in the pull-to-refresh widget but not the image.

Comment: I'm sorry if i made you confusing. but the image part is meant to be still. i wanted to know if i can override the refresh indicator zone to be in specific hight(location) of the screen.

Comment: how about just taking out the image outside of the refresher, why would that not work?

Answer (score 1):

#### This is possibly caused by the Stack widget

- Change your `Stack` to a `Column`
- Wrap your `SmartRefresher` with and `Expanded` widget for your ListviewBuilder to take the remaining space in `vertical axis`. You will have an `unbounded high error` otherwise
- Set the `shrinkwrap` of your ListviewBuilder to `true` for it to build your list elements `on demand`

#### That's it! ☑️